# Make div unfixed after scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling

With the following code, I made my div fixed after you scroll to that div.
But, no my sidebar is scrolling with me, which is fine. But I want it to stop, because otherwise it is overlapping the footer. How do I do this?

I used the following code:

```
var fixmeTop = $('.whitepaper-section').offset().top;
var footer = $('#footer_bg').offset().top;

if ($(window).width() > 1035) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop && currentScroll <= footer) {
            $('.whitepaper-section').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('.whitepaper-section').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
}
```

The website is https://cashcontroller.nl/nieuws/

Regards, Joren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

The thing is that `currentScroll` never can be higher than your `footer` position.

`currentScroll` is the amount of pixels above the viewport. So the "reference" for elements position to pass is the viewport's top. That never happens to your footer, obviously.

**So!** You have to add the `.whitepaper-section` height to `currentScroll` and compare with the footer's position.

Additionnally, `.whitepaper-section` is fixed with a `top` position... You have to add this distance too. I estimated it to 1em in the code below.

```
var fixme = $('.whitepaper-section');
var fixmeTop = fixme.offset().top;
var fixmeHeight = fixme.outerHeight();
var fixedtopOffset = 1em;   // Adjust that with the value you have in CSS .fixed
var footer = $('#footer_bg').offset().top;

if ($(window).width() > 1035) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop && currentScroll + fixmeHeight + fixedtopOffset <= footer) {
            $('.whitepaper-section').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('.whitepaper-section').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try something like `var fixedtopOffset = 10;` The fixed element is at 10 px from top. ;)

Comment: If I use this it works, but then the sidebar disappears when the user reaches the footer. And that is not what I want... I want that the sidebar sticks.